# Who can access Snowflakes organization_usage schema

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I want to be able to export Snowflake cross account cost data to another visualisation tool. I read that cost data are stored in the `organization_usage` schema in the `snowflake` database. In Snowflake documentation it says that users with `accountadmin` role should have access to it. I have an `accountadmin` role but the views in the `organization_usage` schema are empty when I query it. I assume that if I had an `orgadmin` role then I would be able to query it and actually get some result. But is there a way how to access the complete data in `organization_usage` without being an `orgadmin`? This is crucial for me because I would like to create a service that would export these data to another tool, and idealy this service should not use an `orgadmin` user, but it still should be able to access the complete data in `organization_usage` schema.

Answer (score 0):

By default the ORGADMIN role does not have access to the SNOWFLAKE database. You as account admin need to grant access by running below command:

```
grant imported privileges on database snowflake to role orgadmin;
```

You can assign this privilege also to other roles in theory.

Please note that there is a delay of a few hours until data is visible in these views.

Docs: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/organization-usage.html

Comment: It looks like I, as an accountadmin have grant on this schema, but when I query views from it (like warehouse_metering_history), they are always empty. So I assume if I gave grant to some other role, it would also see an empty view. What do you mean by delay? You mean that the most recent data (for example spendings for todays date) will appear after some time? Or that if I query the view, Ill get the result after a few hours asynchronously?

Comment: Delay in terms of "you will see the record a few hours after the event took place". So lets say you are consuming credits in organization A right now. If you query the view in organization_usage right now, it will be empty. The record will be shown in the result set only in a few hours of delay.

Comment: But what about, lets say, credit usage from 1 month ago? Should that be present in the view if I query it rigt now?